# Autocomplete and RadAjaxPanel

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-ajax

I have an three RadAjaxPanels in my page.The first panel has an ASP.net AjaxControlToolkit autocomplete textbox(txtname) and other controls.Based on the textchanged event of txtname I update some of the control values in the remaining two panels.

The issue is when I use a RadAjaxpanel for the autocomplete textbox,its not updating the other controls on the textchange event.But once i remove the RadAjaxPanel1 then the controls are getting updated.

Anyone faced the same issue?Any ideas?

Thanks

```
  <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
<AjaxSettings>
    <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadAjaxPanel1">
        <UpdatedControls>
            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadAjaxPanel2" />
            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadAjaxPanel3" />
        </UpdatedControls>
    </telerik:AjaxSetting>
</AjaxSettings>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Order To Use Ajax before having The RadAjaxManager1 you Should Have The RadScriptManager

```
<telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
 <Scripts>
   <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI"
      Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.Core.js"></asp:ScriptReference>
        <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI"
      Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js"></asp:ScriptReference>
        <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI"
      Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQueryInclude.js"></asp:ScriptReference>
        </Scripts>
    </telerik:RadScriptManager>
```

According To Your Code Your logic Should Be

RadAjaxPanel1 will Update RadAjaxPanel2, RadAjaxPanel3

Also Include RadAjaxPanel1  in Yuor list :

```
     <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadAjaxPanel1">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadAjaxManager1" />
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadAjaxPanel2" />
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadAjaxPanel3" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>

  </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
```

Comment: I already have a AjaxControlToolkit ScriptManager which I am using for my autocomplete textbox,which fetches data from webservice.So I dont think we can use more than one script manager in a page.Some how ajax autocomplete textbox  is not compatible with RadAjaxPanel1.